# android)The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

```
private void Filter_save() {
    MainActivity firstActivity = (MainActivity) MainActivity.firstActivity;
    filter_button = findViewById(R.id.button_filter);
    filter_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            firstActivity.finish(); //Code to close the previous page main activity
            startActivity(intent); //Go to Main Activity
            finish();//Current activity closed
        }

    });
}
```

***I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.***

I'm making an app that displays markers on a map.

The following code controls which markers appear on the map.

There is no problem if you turn off the app by going back or just turn off the app with finish().

However, if you use intents, such as code, you get "The application may be doing too much work on these main threads," and the frame is increasing.

I have to refresh the previous page, main activity, so I am writing the code to turn it over to the intents.

"The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"
This slows down the app and eventually turns off.

Is there any way?

Comment: There isn't really enough here to tell you anything concrete about the Choreographer warning (although that sometimes shows up on slow emulators for otherwise acceptable code), but what is `MainActivity firstActivity = (MainActivity) MainActivity.firstActivity;` doing? That looks expensive, bug-prone, and has a definite "code smell"...

Comment: Yeah, that same line scares me too.  If you have a static reference to an Activity, you're going to have major memory leaks.  If you assume that just because you're in the second activity of your app the first activity still exists and is valid, you're going to be in all sorts of pain.  This has the feel of someone who doesn't really understand the Android model.

Comment: Actually, firstActivity.finish() scares me even more.  Finishing an activity from a reference that may or may not be valid?  That could REALLY screw up the framework.  No activity should ever access ANYTHING about another activity, and they should definitely not be finishing one.

Comment: @TylerV That is just an assignment. Assignments are not expensive. I agree that it seems sketchy and, as Gabe Sechan pointed out, it is indicative of a memory leak.

Comment: @free_coupons_for_sale_1023 The expensive part is finishing and immediately restarting the activity you want to navigate to instead of just updating it's state, not the assignment itself

Comment: @TylerV The calls to `finish()` and `startAcitivty()` are asynchronous; they are not expensive. They perform IPC to notify the OS of the desired behavior and the OS performs it on behalf of the process. That being said, it is unnecessary to finish and re-start the `MainActivity`. Either way, it shouldn't block the main thread by a non-acceptable amount.

Comment: "does not block the main thread" is not the same thing as "not expensive".

Comment: Like I said in my original comment, there's nothing here that would cause the concurrency warning but the extra activity recreation is expensive and, as implemented, buggy. Plus we have no idea what OP is doing in that activity `onCreate` that could be triggered by the extra recreation